# wordpress wp_mail throws error: could not instantiate mail function

Tags: wordpress, email

I have two forms in my website. Both were working fine. but suddenly now they are not working. Emails are not going from both the forms.

// This function gets called when user clicks on submit button

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var $ = jQuery;
            function sendMessage(){
            var name = $('[name="name"]').val();
            var email = $('[name="email"]').val();
            var phone = $('[name="phone"]').val();
            var message = $('[name="message"]').val();
            var filter = /^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/;
            var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

            if(name == '')
            {
                $('.name-error').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $('.name-error').hide();
            }
            if(email == '')
            {
                $('.email-error').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $('.email-error').hide();
            }
            if(phone == '')
            {
                $('.phone-error').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $('.phone-error').hide();
            }
            if(message == '')
            {
                $('.message-error').show();
            }
            else
            {
                $('.message-error').hide();
            }

            if(name != '' && email != '' && phone != '' && message != ''){
                if(emailReg.test(email)){
                    if(filter.test(phone)){
                        var data = {
                            url:        '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>',
                            type:       'POST',
                            action:     'send_mails',
                            formdata: $("#contact").serialize()
                        };

                        var myRequest = jQuery.post(data.url, data, function(response){
                            console.log(response)
                        });

                        myRequest.done(function(){
                            $('#msg').html("<p class='msg' style='background-color:#dff0d8; border-color: #d6e9c6; color:#3c763d; padding:10px; border-radius:4px;'>The Email has been sent successfully!</p>").fadeIn('slow');
                            $('#msg').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                        });
                        $("#contact").trigger("reset");
                        $('#msg').html("<p class='msg' style='background-color:#dff0d8; border-color: #d6e9c6; color:#3c763d; padding:10px; border-radius:4px;'>The Email has been sent successfully!</p>").fadeIn('slow');
                            $('#msg').delay(5000).fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert("Provide valid mobile number");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Provide valid Email Id");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // alert("Kindly enter all the details");
                return false;
            }

        } 
    </script>
```

This is function from functions.php file.

```
    function send_mails()
    {
        $formData = $_POST['formdata'];
        $data = array();
        parse_str($formData, $data);

        $name = $data['name'];
        $email = $data['email'];
        $phone = $data['phone'];
        $message = $data['message'];

        $msg = "A new enquiry has been posted on the website\n";
        $msg.= "Name: ".$name."\n";
        $msg.= "Email: ".$email."\n";
        $msg.= "Phone: ".$phone."\n";
        $msg.= "Message: ".$message."\n";

        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

        //echo $msg;

        $admin_email = get_option( 'admin_email' );
        //  print_r($admin_email);
        $res = wp_mail('email',"Enquiry",$msg,$headers);
        if($res)
        {
            echo "Mail has been sent";

        }
        else
        {
            echo "Could not send mail";
            debug_wpmail($res);
        }

        die();
    }

    add_action('wp_ajax_send_mails', 'send_mails');
    add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_send_mails', 'send_mails');
```

debug_wpmail returns the error "Could not instantiate mail function". I did not find anything on google.

```
if ( ! function_exists('debug_wpmail') ) :
    function debug_wpmail( $result = false ) {
        if ( $result )
            return;
        global $ts_mail_errors, $phpmailer;
        if ( ! isset($ts_mail_errors) )
            $ts_mail_errors = array();
        if ( isset($phpmailer) )
            $ts_mail_errors[] = $phpmailer->ErrorInfo;
        print_r('<pre>');
        print_r($ts_mail_errors);
        print_r('</pre>');
    }
endif;
```

Comment: Could you please check your network for AJAX response?

Comment: @TejasGajjar I am getting this in the network tab - Could not send mail<pre>Array
(
    [0] => Could not instantiate mail function.
)
</pre>

Comment: Could you please change this line to  url:        "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php');?>",where you are passing ajax url.

Comment: And after that, You can try testing with all other plugins deactivated to see if it starts working.

Comment: Maybe you should try sending dummy mail using a simple PHP file to check whether you get that or not. If you get that mail it means your mail function works, and if any error occurs that means there is some PHP mail(); function error. Then you should try using the SMTP plugin to send and receive emails.

Comment: i am getting proper admin_url and i dont have any plugins activated in my website.

Comment: My mailing function was working fine till yesterday. i was able to send mails. but i dont know why it stopped working.

Comment: Do let me know if you stuck in configutations.

Comment: i installed the plugin and chose default PHP mailer and tried to send mail but it shows "There was a problem while sending the test email".

Comment: Do not use default one try to use sendgrid and test the mail with that.

Comment: Now it is working. but i have two forms in my website. One of the email goes in primary tab and the other form email goes in promotions tab. why so?

Comment: The SMTP will just set up the email service. The issue you are mentioning is not related to this please check the code you made for the same.

Comment: yes. your answer helped me. Thank you very much @TejasGajjar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happens due to your site haven't been configured with email service provider like Google/SendGrid or SMTP Or It just goes removed. Example configuration can be found below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify this part :

From

```
$res = wp_mail('email',"Enquiry",$msg,$headers);
```

To

```
$res = wp_mail($admin_email,'Enquiry',$msg,$headers);
```

Comment: i tried with $admin_email and also hardcoding the email id. but did not work.